# Remove the line with the same name but different value

Tags: mysql, sql

So basically I run this code in sql:

```
SELECT p.Nome as Nome_pub, a.Nome as Nome_area, COUNT(*) as total
FROM publicacao p, emprestimo e, area_tematica a
WHERE p.Id=e.Publicacao_Id and p.Area_Tematica_Id=a.Id and (Data_hora>='2021-01-01' AND Data_de_devolucao<='2021-06-31')
GROUP by p.Nome  
ORDER BY Nome_area;
```

and I get the following output

| Nome_pub | Nome_area | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | a | 1 |
| name2 | b | 1 |
| name3 | c | 1 |
| name4 | d | 3 |
| name5 | d | 2 |
| name6 | d | 2 |
| name7 | e | 1 |

but I want an output that gives me the max word3 based on word2 basically: (in my case remove line with "name5" and "name6"

| Nome_pub | Nome_area | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| name1 | a | 1 |
| name2 | b | 1 |
| name3 | c | 1 |
| name4 | d | 3 |
| name7 | e | 1 |

is there any way to do this??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You are using a join syntax that we stopped using about thirty years ago. Who taught you that? Better quit that tutorial, teacher or book. And please switch to explicit joins (`INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

If [ROW_NUMBER](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/) is available in your version.

```
SELECT Nome_pub, Nome_area, total
(
    SELECT 
      p.Nome as Nome_pub
    , a.Nome as Nome_area
    , COUNT(*) as total
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Nome ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as RN
    FROM publicacao p
    JOIN emprestimo e
      ON p.Id = e.Publicacao_Id
    JOIN area_tematica a
      ON a.Id = p.Area_Tematica_Id
    WHERE (        Data_hora >= DATE '2021-01-01' AND 
           Data_de_devolucao <  DATE '2021-07-01')
    GROUP by p.Nome, a.Nome
) q
WHERE RN = 1 
ORDER BY Nome_area;
```

Comment: Yes, that's the straight-forward way. The OP may want to use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER` depending on how they want to deal with ties. And I'd use proper date literals (`Data_hora >= DATE '2021-01-01'`. Depending on the datatype of `Data_de_devolucao`, i.e. in case it can contain a time, too, it can be safer to use an exclusive `Data_de_devolucao < DATE '2021-07-01'`.